# true and false not the same as 1 and 0 for web3 / solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, data-types

When I use `remix` to execute a function with a `bool` field and I put `0` into it (which I interpret as `false`), the `remix` console output tells me `"bool myBool": true` (what I don't understand). So I would like to know:

1. How do I pass `true` or `false` in general via `web3.js` to a `smart contract`, as a string `String(true)`?
2. Is `true` and `false` NOT the same as `1` and `0` for `web3` and/or `solidity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I pass true or false in general via web3.js to a smart
>   contract, as a string String(true)?

In web3 you can use booleans `true` and `false` to pass true or false values for arguments to a contract.

> Is true and false NOT the same as 1 and 0 for web3 and/or solidity?

In solidity you can pass 1 or 0 to refer to `true` and `false` respectively. However, in javascript `true` is not equal to `1` and `false` is not equal to `0`, that is, true===1 is a false statement same for false===0. One may get confused because the statement true==1 is true, but just because js converts between types to find the match, === does not do the conversion.

Hope this helps