# Etherscan Input bool is 1 or true or True

Tags: etherscan

I want to execute a smart contract function that takes input `bool`.

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56083/true-and-false-not-the-same-as-1-and-0-for-web3-solidity) for example makes the distinction that web3 uses javascript which doesn't consider 1 as true, but solidity does consider 1 as true.

So my question is, if a Write Function in Etherscan takes input `bool`, say I want to specify True, do I input **1** or  **true** or **True**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Remix**:

Whatever you pass to the bool parameter will become true except if you pass the value **`false`**.

You can easily check this through a simple contract with Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract Test {
    function isBool(bool check) external pure returns(bool) {
        if (check) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

**In Etherscan**:

Etherscan seems to accept only the following inputs giving these outputs:

- Input: `true` or `1` => returns `true`
- Input: `false` or `0` => returns `false`

Anything different to these input values is returning:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1

Feel free to check it in Ropsten at `0xD394C76C16E7a4a29221218F194A14f6074De6a3`

Comment: what if I pass 0, does that become false too?

Comment: Nop. Passing 0 returns true. 0 is just another number.

Comment: Thanks! You are talking in the context of Etherscan right? 'Im worried I don't know how they parse the inputs.

Comment: Good point. I deployed and verified the contract in Etherscan and apparently the inputs/outputs are slightly different vs. Remix. I'll update my answer.